# Flood modelling (Modifying Dijkstra's to work with a graph where the weight of a path is the maximum weight of its edges.)

Tags: algorithm, graph, traversal, shortest-path, dijkstra

Im trying to program a flood modelling program.

To find the lowest weight path from a start vertex to a vertex, we would intuitively use Dijkstra's. What if the weight of a path is now the maximum weight of its edges? Could we modify Dijkstra's to work with this graph?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtQU4.png

Comment: This question has an answer on another SE site: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18522/widest-path-algorithm-steps

Comment: Please, provide the code of what you have tried, the more details your question have, the easier it will be for others users of the community to find a answer to your issue, such low-effort question should be avoided, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use Prim's algorithm to start generating a minimum spanning tree at your source vertex, and stop when you get to the target vertex.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm